# use controller variables in view angularjs ionic

Tags: angularjs, variables, ionic-framework

I am working in ionic and angular. **I want to set variables in controller and use them in view.** I am using cookies to save current logged in user information.
Here is the controller code:

```
.controller('profileCtrl',['$http','$scope', 
'fileUpload','$cookies','$cookieStore','$window',
 function($http, $scope,    fileUpload,$cookies,$cookieStore,$window) {
    $scope.CurrentUser = $cookieStore.get('CurrentUserInfo');<br/>
    $scope.CurrentUserFullname = $scope.CurrentUser.User.fullname;<br/>
    console.log($scope.CurrentUserFullname); **// working. Suppose name is Simerjit
}])
```

Now in view profile.html. I want to display the name. I use this:
`<h1>{{CurrentUserFullname}}</h1>` **// not working**

Anyone please help. I am new in Ionic and angularjs.

Comment: Define "not working". What happens precisely? Also, is the <h1> in a section of the DOM that is handled by the controller? Post all the relevant code.

Comment: most likely you did some typo in naming controller in the template, please check your template correctly. 

    
<div ng-controller="profileCtrl"> //you should have this somewhere.

or if you use a $routeProvider, check there.

Comment: I check $routeProvider and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the code .That is right but you need to check value of **fullname**  in

$cookieStore.get('CurrentUserInfo');

may be **fullname** has not any value .

I have made many project in ionic you are doing the right way.

## {{CurrentUserFullname}}

Comment: Basically fullname returns me null. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the controller for the profile.html for example `<div ng-controller="profileCtrl">`

Comment: I am using $routProvider file. So it is binding controller and view file automatically. I don't need to specify ng-controller again. Am I right?

Comment: What errors do you get? Are you also loading the angular-route.js and the your-named-controller.js?

Answer (score 0):

if you store user data direcly in cookie then not need it. `$scope.CurrentUser.user.fullname`

you can use directly this.

```
   $scope.CurrentUserFullname = $scope.CurrentUser.fullname;
```

Comment: Thanks. Basically it didn't displayed the fullname. Now issue is fixed. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If your Data Binding not working properly try to use `$route resolve` to get the data into the controller before the view loads .. 
In your  $route  config ,

```
    $routeProvider
    .when("/profile", {
    templateUrl: "profile.html",
    controller: "profileCtrl",
    resolve: {
        CurrentUser: function($cookieStore){
            return $cookieStore.get('CurrentUserInfo');
    }
}})
```

and in Controller inject  `CurrentUser`

```
    .controller('profileCtrl',['$http','$scope','CurrentUser' fileUpload','$cookies','$cookieStore','$window', function($http, $scope,CurrentUser,fileUpload,$cookies,$cookieStore,$window) {
       $scope.CurrentUser = CurrentUser;
       $scope.CurrentUserFullname = CurrentUser.User.fullname;
       console.log($scope.CurrentUserFullname); }])
```

for more info on resolve [link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx)

happy coding ...

Answer (score -3):

Controller shouldn't know about app's state.
You should read about angular's rules and best practices there:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: Any relation between question and answer?